# How to get relation table column using TypeORM find option?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

```
const user = await this.userService.FindOne({
        where: {
            id: req.body.id,
        },
        relations: ['roleUser'],
    });
console.log('User Role Id:' + user.roleUser.id);
```

How can I get relation table (roleUser) column value ?

Comment: have you create model file ?

Comment: oh yeah, am having User and RoleUser Model